# Magento Checkout : Get Subtotal Value without iterating

Tags: magento

```
<?php
foreach($this->getTotals() as $total)
{
    if ($total->getCode() == 'subtotal')
    {
        $subtotal = $total->getValue();
        break;
    }
}
echo $subtotal;
?>
```

Any way to get subtotal directly ?

Answer (score 27):

According to [this site](http://sleekd.com/general/how-to-set-up-tax-rules-for-sales-within-canada-in-magento/):

> You can get the subtotal with:
>
> ```
> $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();
> $subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
> ```

Answer (score 12):

Try to use this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal()
```

Comment: For this to work , its important that the rates are already collected. If not the quote will not have the subtotal to return.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
$subtotal = $this->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
```

Comment: There seems to be an important difference between this and the answer below. $this->getQuote()->getSubtotal() does does not include tax, but $totals = Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/cart’)->getQuote()->getTotals(); $totals["subtotal"]->getValue(); does include tax

Answer (score 0):

```
    $session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $getotal = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
    $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
    $subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
```

"**$subtotal**" will hold the value of subtotal .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Subtotal cart with taxes:

url: http://niravkadiya.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/sub-total-of-cart-including-tax-without-shipping/

It work me!!