# Get the value for discount in cart

Tags: shopping-cart, cart, discount, coupon

If we have a coupon code that say gives a 5% discount....how can I grab the discounted value into a variable?  For example $100 subtotal with a 5% discount.  The value of the discount would be 5.  I need to get the "5" into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer [Magento Checkout : Get Subtotal Value without iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245436/magento-checkout-get-subtotal-value-without-iterating)

I was able to add another variable for discount:

```
$discount = $totals["discount"]->getValue();
```